# nodeJs Invalid listen argumen

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

```
var http = require('http');

var port = process.argv.slice(2);

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  setInterval(function(){
    response.write(new Date() + "\n");

  }, 1000);

  //response.end('Hello World\n'); //we cant use the .write after the end. 
}).listen(port);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:" + port);
```

executing: node server.js 3000

gettint the error:

> Throw new Error('Invalid listen argument: ' + h);
>                 ^ Error: Invalid listen argument: 3000

What do i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `port` appears to be an empty array, it's not an appropriate parameter for `listen()`
Try to log `port` before its usage

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your `port` is of type `object`.
Do one of the following:

```
var port = parseInt(process.argv.slice(2)); //Make use of `parseInt` to change it to a number

//OR

.listen(parseInt(port));
```